# Starting hotspot using console Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, networking, lightdm, services

I know how to create a hotspot using graphical interface but it seems like a lot of energy and resources get wasted just to keep my laptop on with all the GUI services running just to use as a hotspot. So I tried stopping the `lightdm` service, but then my hotspot too stopped.

I want to use my hotspot while `lightdm` service is stopped.
Any ideas or a better solution to conserve energy and resources just to keep my hotspot running using my laptop?